# Does Google manually review all app updates for Android Auto?

Tags: android, google-play, android-auto

I am working on an update to make my already published App compatible with Android Auto.
As I read in Google design Guidelines this update has to be approved by Google to then be available for distribution.

https://developer.android.com/docs/quality-guidelines/auto-app-quality

But does this mean that every update I publish from this date on needs to be manually reviewed and approved by Google, even if it doesn't change anything on the Android Auto integration of this app? 
Or is it just the initial update?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a customer support quesiton

Comment: @Zoe this is a valid question since it's not crystal clear in the developer portal.

Comment: Because it's not explained in the docs doesn't make it on-topic. Related meta posts: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165/6296561 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions

Comment: @Zoe Thanks, didn't know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's all updates.

> Note that if the submitted app is an update to an existing app and your updated app does not meet the review criteria, the update is rejected and the existing app remains published in the Google Play store.

You can read more about the Android Auto [distrubution here](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/launch/distribute-auto.html)

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I understood this as just referring to the initial update, but it does make sense..